# Get locale (language) of website visitor?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a webite and I'm trying to guess how to get the clients current locale.... This web does use JQuery and Javascript a lot, so is there any way using it?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with this locale information? There are already locale-aware JS functions for things like `Date`.

Comment: @LeonKramer locale != location

Comment: @Ibu, this page is the first result when you search for "jquery get locale".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](https://github.com/dansingerman/jQuery-Browser-Language) `jQuery` plugin for obtain the browser language setting.

Example usage:

```
$.browserLanguage(function( language , acceptHeader ){
    alert("You have your browser language set to " + language);
})
```

Comment: Interesting plugin - except it reports I live in High Wycombe, which is news to me.

Comment: @Utkanos Sadly, IP GeoLocation isn’t exact enough.